# WCF constructor Service Type via DI

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, servicehost

I'm currently trying to build a small App-Server which shall host multiple WCF services. These services (and their dependencies of course) should be instantiated by an DI/IoC Container (currently LightCore but since I am using it via the CommonServiceLocator it should be easy to exchange). 
Unfortunately I stumbled onto a problem. Obviously I have to create ServiceHost instances to host mentioned WCF services. I already built a customized InstanceProvider and ServiceBehavior to handle all dependencies of the services, BUT the Constructor of ServiceHost needs the Service Type of the service to host. At this point in my program, I only know the Interface Type, since only the DI container knows which Service implementation is currently being used.

A cheap method would be to create a "dummy" instance of the service type via Service Locator and give the ServiceHost constructor the output of myDummyInstance.GetType(), but that just hurts to look at, useless instantiation and usage of Service Locator instead of DI...there has to be a better way.

Any ideas anyone? :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways how to do that.

- The way I like is very simple. You will not resolve contract of your service but service implementation itself because simply that is what WCF expects. All IoC containers I used are able to resolve type itself and fill its dependencies.
- Another way is little bit more hack. When you call the constructor of service host you will resolve type of the service contract by call like `ServiceLocator.Resolve<IContract>().GetType()`. It is ugly but it is much more clean then creating dummy implementations. Moreover you never know if the passed type is not used for something else in the infrastructure so passing dummy type can be dangerous.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately the CommonServiceLocator does not seem to allow/support your first way (or I misunderstood it), that would've been the perfect solution though.
The second way wouldn't be a big difference to my dummy instance. I don't have an instance-reference laying around, true, but it uses the ServiceLocator (maybe inevitable) and also creates a dummy instance, just no reference to it :).